# remove exited job from qstat list

Tags: jobs, global-asax, pbs, torque

I'm working on a PBS server and when I type qstat -u username -t I get the following output:

```
                                                                         Req'd  Req'd   Elap
Job ID               Username Queue    Jobname          SessID NDS   TSK Memory Time  S Time
-------------------- -------- -------- ---------------- ------ ----- --- ------ ----- - -----
13631484[2648].p     username long     pre_scan_pdf-264   6824     1  --    4gb 167:5 R 46:20
13631484[2662].p     username long     pre_scan_pdf-266  28333     1  --    4gb 167:5 R 76:10
13631506[3732].p     username short    ew_scan-3732      13625   --   --    4gb 01:29 E 00:14
```

So my problem is, that as you can see there is a job which has exited.

I want to remove this job from the list, because I have a script running which checks if the expression "short " occurs in the qstat -u username -t output. If this occures then no jobs are submitted.

Therefore i tried something like qdel 13631506[] to remove the exited job from the list, but that did not work.

Comment: Isn't it what the "keep_completed" parameter of the queue configuration controls? Could you please check if the value is greater than 0? `qmgr -c "print queue short keep_completed"`

Comment: I executed your command. The output is just #
# Create queues and set their attributes.
#
#
# Create and define queue short
#
create queue short

Comment: `keep_completed` doesn't apply to exiting jobs. See my answer below for ideas. What version are you on?

Answer (score 3):

There are some known bugs with jobs sometimes getting stuck in exiting status, so you could be running into one of those, but perhaps the epilogue is simply taking longer than you'd like to finish. You can set `$prologalarm` (in `TORQUE_HOME/mom_priv/config` on the compute nodes) to limit how long `pbs_mom` will wait before killing job processes that get stuck in the prologue or epilogue script stage, but you'll probably want to check the job processes on the node first, to troubleshoot and see if you can figure out what's going wrong there. (Speaking to Dmitri Chubarov's comment, `keep_completed` only applies for completed jobs, not exiting ones.)

You can also purge jobs with `qdel -p <job_id>` but that simply tells the server to forget everything it knows about a job. In more recent versions, the server has been modified to be authoritative, with respect to "stray" jobs that it doesn't know about, so it should then force the MOM(s) to clear the job. However, I'd only recommend purging as a last resort.